# showing the most used amino acid at each sequencing position and at what frequency

Tags: python, count

I am trying to find the most used amino acid at each sequencing position (there are 27 positions in all  of these sequences) and also to know the amino acid frequency in each position.If anyone could give me some ways, I will be really apprceate! Thanks!

```
NDVLPDEMTSIDNRPLPFIYQFTAGAI
IPAYITEMNGNSTNNEQLQQELATTQD
LEKALLYMLPLYLLTNAKGQQMQIELK 
YDMATNGMSKLFSTVNSARHSVPLGGM 
VEHLYSAMSANGKISVPEAVVNWLFKV
```

Comment: You should provide example output so we know what you are trying to achieve, your description isn't entirely clear.

Answer (score -1):

This may give you something to start with. The format of output may need be changed. You change it to read the aa sequences from a file and to handle variable sequence length. And you also need to handle ties.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import print_function

seqs = ['NDVLPDEMTSIDNRPLPFIYQFTAGAI',
        'IPAYITEMNGNSTNNEQLQQELATTQD',
        'LEKALLYMLPLYLLTNAKGQQMQIELK',
        'YDMATNGMSKLFSTVNSARHSVPLGGM',
        'VEHLYSAMSANGKISVPEAVVNWLFKV']

num = len(seqs)
aafre = []
for i in range(27):
    aafre.append({})

most = []

for seq in seqs:
    for i in range(27):
        aa = seq[i]
        if not aa in aafre[i]:
            aafre[i][aa] = 0
        aafre[i][aa] += 1

for i in range(27):
    most.append([0, ''])
    for aa in aafre[i]:
        if most[i][0] < aafre[i][aa]:
            most[i] = [aafre[i][aa], aa]
    print(str(i+1) + ': ' + most[i][1] + ' ' + str(most[i][0]), end="")
    for aa in aafre[i]:
        print(', ' + aa + ' ' + str(aafre[i][aa]), end="")
    print('')
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not 100% sure your desired outcome, but my interpretation is for each 27 sequence positions you want to know how many times each amino-acid (represented by a single letter) occurs at each position, and which appears most frequently?

I started by finding which amino acid occurs most frequently within each sequence.

```
i = 1
for seq in lst.split(" "):
    print( i, max( set(seq), key=seq.count ) )
    i = i+1
```

Result

```
1 I
2 N
3 L
4 S
5 V
```

Now using *numpy* I can transpose the sequences, meaning I can examine them vertically instead of horizontally, so five lines 27 characters long would become 27 lines 5 characters long, then I could use the same method on each of the 27 lines to see which is the most frequently occurring letter.

```
import numpy as np
lst = 'NDVLPDEMTSIDNRPLPFIYQFTAGAI IPAYITEMNGNSTNNEQLQQELATTQD LEKALLYMLPLYLLTNAKGQQMQIELK YDMATNGMSKLFSTVNSARHSVPLGGM VEHLYSAMSANGKISVPEAVVNWLFKV'
arr = []
for seq in lst.split(" "):
    arr.append( list(seq) )
df = np.array( arr )
df = df.T
i = 1
for seq in df:
    seq_str = ''.join(str(x) for x in seq)
    print( i, max( set(seq_str), key=seq_str.count ) )
    i = i+1
```

Result.

```
1 I
2 E
3 M
4 L
...
26 G
27 M
```

If there is a tie, one of the letters will be picked arbitrarily.

To see the list of amino acids occurring at each position, you could use

```
print( i, max( set(seq_str), key=seq_str.count ), set(seq_str) )
```

Result

```
8 M {'M'}
9 S {'S', 'T', 'N', 'L'}
10 G {'G', 'S', 'P', 'A', 'K'}
11 L {'I', 'L', 'N'}
```

Lastly, to see how many times of each of those letters occur, you can use

```
    print( i, max( set(seq_str), key=seq_str.count ), {y:seq_str.count(y) for y in set(seq_str)})
```

Result

```
8 M {'M': 5}
9 S {'S': 2, 'T': 1, 'N': 1, 'L': 1}
10 G {'G': 1, 'S': 1, 'P': 1, 'A': 1, 'K': 1}
11 L {'I': 1, 'L': 2, 'N': 2}
```